# Named route from resources takes me to show page instead of delete page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, resources, restful-url

I am using `resources :users` in `routes.rb`. This provides the following paths as `rake routes` unveils.

```
users     GET    /users(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
          POST   /users(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user  GET    /users/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user      GET    /users/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

Further, I comment out the legacy wild controller route.

```
#match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

To add a **delete** link on my users page I add the following.

```
<%= link_to "Delete user", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

This generated the following html code.

```
<a href="/users/42" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete user</a>
```

I click the link and it takes me to the **show** page?! What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the default Javascript files for that to work properly:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```